# Background color not showing up in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Can't for the life of me figure out why the gray background on the top slider, to the right of the video, is not showing up in safari. The css looks fine and works in other browsers.  Anyone have a clever idea?  Thanks
http://www.cope24.com/
This is Safari  5.1.7.[image: screenshot from Firefox]

Comment: what version?, what colour is expected and what is shown? code?

Comment: can you perhaps include screenshots of expected appearance and of bug please. it doesn't quite look right to me on chrome either: http://cl.ly/image/2G3p2N42092U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the width on `<div id="maintext">` by a few pixels and it shows up just fine on Chrome & Safari .. and FF 19 + IE 9

Also you're using the deprecated `iFrame` frameborder attribute .. get rid of that

---

420px (what it is currently):

[image]

418px:

[image]

Comment: I knocked <div id="maintext"> by 30px, reduced the slider width and tried a few other things and I still can't get the box to show in Safari or Chrome.  I see the box load for just a second in Chrome, then it is gone. Afraid I know nothing about iframe and it all seems to be built in to the plugin.

Comment: Yep, it is 397px. hmmm, this is interesting.  I made the whole slider background gray and it shows the background now, but not the text box.  I should have mentioned, this is Safari/Chrome on mac.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to float the iframe so both that and the DIV appear side by side.

Just add:

```
.content iframe {float:left;}
```

Comment: the .content iframe {float:left;} was really what fixed it in all browsers.  thanks so much